# Исправить прерывистое рисование на CANVAS

Tags: canvas

Если вести мышь медленно, то промежутков нет, но стоит немного ускорить, появляются очень большие пробелы. Как можно исправить? Или нужен вообще другой подход?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 678;


canvas.onmousedown = function() {
  let flag = true;
  draw();
  canvas.onmousemove = function() {
    if (flag == true) {
      draw();
    }
  }
  canvas.onmouseup = function() {
    flag = false;
  }
  canvas.onmouseout = function() {
    flag = false;
  }
};

function draw() {
  let x = event.offsetX;
  let y = event.offsetY;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

}
```

```html
<style>
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

Естественно, будет просвет между Вашими квадратиками, если Вы двинули мышь больше, чем на пять пикселей.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 678;
var oldPoint = null;
let flag = false;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  flag = true;
  draw(e);
};
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (flag == true) {
    draw(e);
  }
};
canvas.onmouseup = function() {
  oldPoint = null;
  flag = false;
};
canvas.onmouseout = function() {
  oldPoint = null;
  flag = false;
};

function draw(event) {
  if (!oldPoint) {
    oldPoint = { x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY };
  }

  ctx.moveTo(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.stroke();

  oldPoint.x = event.offsetX;
  oldPoint.y = event.offsetY;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```